# All lines not being read while executing read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv

This is the input file: http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=841283 . I executed

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x=read.csv("test1.csv", header = FALSE, sep="'").
```

The result is this: http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=841284

Instead of giving 135 rows, I am getting only 7 rows! Number of columns is correct, and is 13. x[6,10] has the content of the rows following it as well, just separated by \n in the string.

Please help me in this. I am stuck up in this problem! :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The described symptom of an extremely long item with multiple "\n"'s suggests you probably need to deal with unmatched quotes. If there is a quote mark in a name or address entry then the parser will wait for the next one before considering hte entry complete. Try"

```
x=read.csv("test1.csv", header = FALSE, sep="'", quote="")
```

That didn't actually work on the file I downloaded. (And do note that the sep argument will be ignored in `read.csv`.) I needed to first use count.fields with that separator and then using `read.table` with `fill =TRUE`. The results were still a bit messed up with several columns being populated with commas but at least there is something to work with:

```
table( count.fields("~/Downloads/test1.txt", sep="'", quote=""))

 10  13 
  5 130 
 x <- read.table("~/Downloads/test1.txt", header = FALSE, sep="'", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=5)
#Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#  line 6 did not have 13 elements
 x <- read.table("~/Downloads/test1.txt", header = FALSE, sep="'", 
                  quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
 str(x)
 #########################################################
'data.frame':   135 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ V1 : chr  "INSERT INTO message VALUES (52," "INSERT INTO message VALUES (53," "INSERT INTO message VALUES (54," "INSERT INTO message VALUES (55," ...
 $ V2 : chr  "press.release@enron.com" "office.chairman@enron.com" "office.chairman@enron.com" "press.release@enron.com" ...
 $ V3 : chr  "," "," "," "," ...
 $ V4 : chr  "2000-01-21 04:51:00" "2000-01-24 01:37:00" "2000-01-24 02:06:00" "2000-02-02 10:21:00" ...
 $ V5 : chr  "," "," "," "," ...
 $ V6 : chr  "<12435833.1075863606729.JavaMail.evans@thyme>" "<29664079.1075863606676.JavaMail.evans@thyme>" "<15300605.1075863606629.JavaMail.evans@thyme>" "<10522232.1075863606538.JavaMail.evans@thyme>" ...
 $ V7 : chr  "," "," "," "," ...
 $ V8 : chr  "ENRON HOSTS ANNUAL ANALYST CONFERENCE PROVIDES BUSINESS OVERVIEW AND GOALS FOR 2000" "Over $50 -- You made it happen!" "Over $50 -- You made it happen!" "ROAD-SHOW.COM Q4i.COM CHOOSE ENRON TO DELIVER FINANCIAL WEB CONTENT" ...
 $ V9 : chr  "," "," "," "," ...
 $ V10: chr  "HOUSTON - Enron Corp. hosted its annual equity analyst conference today in==20Houston.  Ken Lay, Enron chairman and chief execu"| __truncated__ "On Wall Street, people are talking about Enron.  At Enron, we re talking=20about people...our people.  You are the driving forc"| __truncated__ "On Wall Street, people are talking about Enron.  At Enron, we re talking=20about people...our people.  You are the driving forc"| __truncated__ "HOUSTON =01) Enron Broadband Services (EBS), a wholly owned subsidiary of E=nron=20Corp. and a leader in the delivery of high-b"| __truncated__ ...
 $ V11: chr  "" "," "," "," ...
 $ V12: chr  "" "Robert_Badeer_Aug2000Notes FoldersPress releases" "Robert_Badeer_Aug2000Notes FoldersPress releases" "Robert_Badeer_Aug2000Notes FoldersPress releases" ...
 $ V13: chr  "" ");" ");" ");" ...
```

I got better results with a comma as separator and just single quote rather than the default single- or double-quote that the `read.*`-functions use:

```
x2 <- read.table("~/Downloads/test1.txt", header = FALSE, sep=",",
                  quote="'", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
 str(x2)
```

Comment: Well I got the desired result with just using quote="" in my original code! And to get rid of the commas, I copied the desired columns in another data frame.

Comment: The other gotcha' that sometimes needs fixing is the comment character argument. The `count.fields` function accepts alterations in that parameter and wrapping it in `table` lets you quickly check the regularity of alternative choices for both parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Check your text and think of what you expect from it when you were a computer. It starts without a delimiter ('), sees the first (') in `press releases`, and starts to do stupid things after this. Don't count your first entries which are read, check the output first.

```
INSERT INTO message VALUES (52,'press.release@enron.com','2000-01-21 04:51:00','<12435833.1075863606729.JavaMail.evans@thyme>','ENRON HOSTS
```

Comment: The texts in each column are correct and as expected, except for the no of rows problem!                                                      
Also I just made some editing to the content in 6th row. I observed that it was the lenthiest row, so I deleted some content in the "message" part, so that it is no longer the lengthiest row. And when I ran the code again, I got the no of rows correct and as expected!!!

But I can't edit my dataset like this :/ This will give incorect result, and also this is enron dataset.. quite large!

Comment: Just to understand what you did: Have you tried to delete line 7, and then things were ok? If not (or even if): try to set variable colClasses explicitly (probably all strings). It anyway is the most important trick to speed up readTable.