# Reading in text file with unmatched quotes

Tags: r, csv

I have a large (>1GB) CSV file I'm trying to read into a data frame in R.

The non-numeric fields are enclosed in double-quotes so that internal commas are not interpreted as delimiters. That's well and good. However, there are also sometimes unmatched double-quotes in an entry, like `"2" Nails"`.

What is the best way to work around this? My current plan is to use a text processor like awk to relabel the quoting character from the double-quote `"` to a non-conflicting character like pipe `|`. My heuristic for finding quoting characters would be double-quotes next to a comma:

```
gawk '{gsub(/(^\")|(\"$)/,"|");gsub(/,\"/,",|");gsub(/\",/,"|,");print;}' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763294/all-lines-not-being-read-while-executing-read-csv-in-r/17763959) is related, but the solution (argument in `read.csv` of `quote=""`) is not viable for me because my file has non-delimiting commas enclosed in the quotation marks.

Comment: I don't see how changing all "\"" to "|" would be helpful. I think you might need a regex solution (probably implememted in awk) that will find instances of something like: ","\"[^,]{0,}\"[^,]{0,}\"," , i.e. three double-quotes between commas.

Comment: @DWin See edit. If I changed the quoting double-quotes to pipes then I could set `quote='|'` in `read.csv`.

Comment: You could, of course, do that but you will have the same parsing difficulties that you are currently experiencing. Try it on a small test case. In your test case there would be two offending doble quotes, one next to the first dbl-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of looking for quotes next to a comma is probably the best thing you can do; you could however try to turn it around and have the regex escape all the quotes that are *not*  next to a comma (or start/end of line):

Search for

```
(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)
```

and replace all the matches with `""`.

R might not be the best tool for this because its regex engine doesn't have a multiline mode, but in Perl it would be a one-liner:

```
$subject =~ s/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/""/mg;
```

Comment: Why do you need the multiline option? I ran this in the command line: `perl -p -e 's/(?<!,)(?<!^)"(?!,|$)/""/mg;' file1.csv > file2.csv`

Comment: If you run the command line by line, you don't need the multiline option. But if you have read the entire file into `$subject`, then you do need it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a more foolproof variant of Tim's solution, in case non-boundary commas exist inside the cell:

```
(?<!,\s+)"(?!\s+,$)
```

I'm not sure if it would have any bugs though.